# WordPress/WC session not carried to next page

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

Simply trying to store and retrieve unregistered customer data from page to page in a custom checkout template. I've stripped it down to the bare bones to try to pinpoint the issue.

This

```
<?php
    $customer = WC()->customer;
    $customer->set_billing_first_name("WORKING!!!");
    $customer->save();
    var_dump($customer->get_billing());
?>
```

Outputs this

```
array (size=2)
'country' => string 'US' (length=2)
'first_name' => string 'WORKING!!!' (length=10)
```

But then this

```
<?php
    $customer = WC()->customer;
    //$customer->set_billing_first_name("WORKING!!!");
    //$customer->save();
    var_dump($customer->get_billing());
?>
```

Outputs this

```
array (size=1)
'country' => string 'US' (length=2)
```

Even though I should still be firmly within the same session, and therefore should get the data stored before the comments. All I did was refresh the page after commenting out those two lines.

*Am I completely wrong about these methods?*

---

**Checked**

1. Environment is configured entirely correctly. Even had someone else double-check it for me. URLs, caches, etc.
2. It does appear to work when logged in, but the vast majority of users never do so that's not very helpful.
3. Have tried this on two different servers (one local, one remote) and have the same issue.
4. Started fresh with a new WP+WC install, created a blank theme, functions.php that does the above on init code. Same exact issue.

Comment: That is a normal thing if `$customer->get_id()` is `0` which happens when you're not logged-in. WooCommerce stores the session identifier (the user ID or an auto-generated customer ID) in the browser's cookies, and not the superglobal `$_SESSION`. Try `var_dump( $customer->get_billing(), $customer->get_id(), WC->session->get_customer_id() )` and see the output when you're logged-in and not.

Comment: @SallyCJ ah okay so my root assumption that this stores customer data in a session is false? I am seeing the `wp_woocommerce_session_xxx=yyyy` cookie passed up in the request... it there a built-in way to store this customer data temporarily?

Comment: Your assumption is basically true; however, the session data (other than the session identifier; e.g. cart contents) are stored in `{prefix}woocommerce_sessions` table - e.g. `wp_woocommerce_sessions`. And this is same to how the WordPress authentication works, where your user ID is saved in the cookie, but the rest of your session are saved in the database. You can use `WC()->session->set()` to save data temporarily, which can persist across pages - but of course cookies must be enabled in the user's browser.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm seeing the same issue, using `WC()->session`, setting a var, then commenting out the set and refreshing the page. The value I saved and successfully returned using `WC()->session->set()` and `WC()->session->get()` is just flat out not there after navigation.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know how it goes. Hopefully it works..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `$customer->save()` doesn't persist the changes you made to the customer's data (e.g. `$customer->set_billing_first_name('Test')`), then it's likely because the customer is not registered to the site or not logged-in, where `$customer->get_id()` is `0`.

And that is normal because the user's ID or the session's ID is required in order to properly save the changes and make it persistent across different pages.

*So when the user is not registered/logged-in, WooCommerce doesn't start its session until the user logs in, or that he/she added a product into the cart.*

But you can manually start the session, like so: (add the code to the active theme's `functions.php` file)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', function(){
    if ( ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
} );
```

And then, changes to the customer's data would then be carried on to other pages so long as *cookies* are enabled on the browser, because just like WordPress, WooCommerce stores its session ID (the user ID or an auto-generated ID/hash) in the cookies — and the session ID is used to set/retrieve the session data in the database — the table name is `woocommerce_sessions` if without any table prefix.

Try this after starting the WooCommerce session:

```
$customer = WC()->customer;
// Change 'Test' if necessary - e.g. 'Something unique 123'
if ( 'Test' !== $customer->get_billing_first_name() ) {
    $customer->set_billing_first_name( 'Test' );
    echo 'First name added to session<br>';
} else {
    echo 'First name read from session<br>';
}
```

And this one — you should see a new date on each page load: (well, the one you've set previously)

```
echo WC()->session->get( 'test', 'None set' ) . '<br>';
WC()->session->set( 'test', current_time( 'mysql' ) );
echo WC()->session->get( 'test', 'It can\'t be empty' );
```

Comment: You are my hero today. I would seriously pay you to answer my questions about WP. So many gaps in my knowledge...

Comment: Well, I always learned from people's code, and eventually became better in time. And I'm sure you too can. :) But hey, I also still have gaps in my knowledge because nobody is perfect... xD And you can always ask your question on Stack Overflow - or for *WordPress-specific* like creating custom WordPress REST API endpoints, then you should ask it on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions). (Note though, WooCommerce questions are off-topic there..)

Comment: Been stuck on this one for days, you seem like you understand the bones much better than I do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362482/shipping-cost-not-showing-in-cart-total-woocommerce

Comment: Sorry Randy, I forgot about that question, and by the time I wanted to answer it, you've already posted an answer, so I +1 it and I'm sure all is good now. :)

Comment: Had the same issue with session refreshing while cart was empty (and not logged in). I ask for info before proceeding to cart so it was a bit annoying to workaround, and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Url set in Wordpress? It seems that it stores the cookie based on the url configured in the app rather than the actual one.

Hope this helps.

Source: https://en.blogpascher.com/wordpress-tutorial/How-correct-the-loss-of-session-on-wordpress

Comment: This is actually a local copy of my site. Do you have a quick reference for where/what settings to check?

Comment: Either in wp-config.php or in the interface under General Settings

Comment: Check WP_SITEURL In wp-config.php

Comment: Interestingly, there is no WP_SITEURL set in the wp-config.php in the root of this site. As in the property is not listed. This is a site that is hosted on wpengine and they do have some custom settings in here, but I'm uncertain if that would have any effect. But I like this train of thought, working through more now